# Set Input To Default Audio Device ( SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice() )

Tags: c#, audio, input, default, device

Good day,
 I need help with this command i cant find how repair it.
 It would be a recognition voice to text.

I have win7 and .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
I am using Visual studio 2010 and i am programming in C#.

Problem:
 ...
 private SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 ...

_recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();// All works but here is problem.
 ...
 }
 ...

---

When i run it.

System.PlatformNotSupportedException

No recognizer is installed.

Thanks for help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running the program on a Windows XP machine.

Check the Platform section for a list of supported platforms for that class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx

Some features in the .NET framework require specific libraries which are not available on all versions of Windows that support .NET.

Even if you have a compatible platform, the library might be a addon you need to enable through the Control Panel, or download from the Microsoft website.